# Issue with v-if in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

I have a modal. In that modal I am displaying a table. One of `tr` of that table is like below

```
<tr>
    <td class="ui header">Name</td>
    <td v-if="editValue">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">                                 
    </td>
    <td v-else>
        {{ addressObj.name }}  
        <span @click="change_value" class="edit_span">
              Edit
        </span>   
    </td>
</tr>
```

The `change_value` is like below

```
change_value() {
    this.editValue = true;
}
```

If I click on `Edit` the input box is displayed but the modal is disappearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@click.stop.prevent="change_value"`

It's likely that the click has somehow triggered the modal closing. Adding `event.stopPropogation()` and `event.preventDefault()` should help you avoid that.

`.prevent` add 'event.preventDefault()' to the click event

`.stop` add 'event.stopPropogation()' to the click event

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers